# Can a WebKit webplugin be configured to load and run on every page?

Tags: objective-c, plugins, safari, webkit, mobile-safari

WebKit's (or Safari's) plugin architecture seems to rely heavily on MIME types (which makes sense, of course). Is it true that a Safari will only load a plugin when it encounters an embed or object tag that loads a file of the MIME type that the plugin handles?

To rephrase my question: Is it possible to create WebKit plugin that loads or runs on every page (for example to manipulate the DOM on every page)? I know that I can do that with Safari 5's extensions, but I'm targeting mobile Safari which does not support extensions (but does support *.webplugin's on jailbroken devices or the Simulator).

Thanks!

- Johannes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my understanding, WebKit plugins require presence of their declared MIME type. Sorry.

Comment: Thanks, Wolf. I know that a lot of desktop Safari plugins use SIMBL to get around this. Since I could only install a webplugin on a jailbroken iPhone, I could also use  http://iphonedevwiki.net/index.php/MobileSubstrate to alter Mobile Safari's behavior, like this example: http://thebigboss.org/2009/08/02/safari-download-manager-100-is-out